# SharePoint 2013 custom voting board workflows accross multiple lists

Tags: designer-workflow, custom

Good morning,

I have set up a site specifically for members to vote on items that are submitted and then the item transitions throughout multiple lists during various stages of the process.  I have it set up as such:

List A:
A new item is submitted and an email is sent to a distro to vote via comments.
The workflow is set to remove permissions from them after 5 days.
Once a specific field value is entered, the item is copied to List B and retained in List A for comments.

The emails are sent, the timer ticks down, the permissions are stripped away, but the item is not copied over to List B.

Both lists are exactly the same as far as columns and settings.  The only thing different is permissions for who can modify/view items.

I am trying to get it to function correctly so that I don't have to continue to modify the workflow after the fact in order to get it copied over.  I am also trying to find a way to have the comments copy over as well.  The item is only retained in List A so that the voting board chairman can still access the version history to view/print comments and then delete the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short form...

We ended up deciding that permissions weren't an issue and by granting all parties involved in the voting process the same library access, the issue was resolved.

All items will copy from List A to List B as long as the people or group that is submitting the intitial items have access to List B.